# Unable to get OpenGL ES 'draw' functions to work (+ C99 error) with Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to compile some example code from the **Cocos2d for iPhone 0.99 Beginner's Guide**.:

```
-(void)draw
{
    if(isSelected)
    {
        [self.mySprite setOpacity:100];
        glColor4f(255 / 255.0f, 0 / 255.0f, 0 / 255.0f, 255 / 255.0f);
        glPointSize( 30.0 );
        ccDrawPoint( self.mySprite.position);
    }
    [super draw];
}
```

Apart from this not actually drawing a rectangular highlight on top of the sprite when isSelected = YES, the gl functions are also giving me warnings:

- Implicit declaration of function 'glPointSize' is invalid in C99
- Implicit declaration of function 'glColor4f' is invalid in C99

Comment: Are you using cocos2d 2.0? The code above will only work with cocos2d v1.1 or earlier.

Comment: Yes I am using cocos2d 2.0. Is there a way to update the code so that it works with 2.0? I was reading the migration guide but I can't for the life of me figure this out yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using Cocos2D 2.x? Try `ccDrawColor4F` instead of `glColor4f` and `ccPointSize` instead of `glPointSize`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to #import

You can use:
 **ccDrawSolidRect**(<#CGPoint origin#>, <#CGPoint destination#>, <#ccColor4F color#>)

This is probably a neater way to have a highlighted rectangle than using ccDrawPoint().

Hope this helps.